# あなたの仕事なんですか？Anata no shigoto nan desu ka? Is this correct grammatically?

Tags: grammar

> あなたの仕事なんですか？
>   Anata no shigoto nan desu ka?

Is this correct grammatically?

I understand that "no" means possession, therefore "your job" is this correct thinking?

Also, I heard someone say:

"Doko no iku ka?" But shouldn't it be "Doko ni iku ka?"

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two questions here.

---

**First question:**

> あなたの仕事なんですか？

I see one small hiccup with your grammar.  As you have noted the `の` is the possessive particle here, it is used correctly.

The hiccup I see is that you are missing the `は` particle in this sentence.  `は` marks the subject of the sentence (among many other uses).  The subject of this sentence is `あなたの仕事.`  Therefore, I would correct your sentence to be:

> あなたの仕事｛しごと｝**は**なんですか？
>   anata no shigoto **wa** nan desu ka?

---

**Second Question:**

> Also, I heard someone say, "Doko no iku ka?" But shouldn't it be "Doko ni iku ka?"

A [dictionary search of other words spelled iku](https://jisho.org/search/iku) made it clear that there is no *relevant* noun spelled iku.  It is always good to check the dictionary for possible duplicate meanings in these cases.

The iku that you want is **[行｛い｝く](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F)**, or `to go` (among other meanings).

> shouldn't it be "Doko ni iku ka?"

Yes, but I would like to make a point about the use of か here.  Using か with plain form verbs can come off as abrupt or patronizing if you are not careful.  As a beginner, I suggest that you stick to `...ますか` and `...ですか` until you gain more experience. Say it like this:

> どこに行｛い｝きますか？
>   doko ni ikimasu ka?